# Should I include/mention licenses of dependencies of 3rd party software used by my software?

Tags: software, licensing

I have a project that depends on numerous 3rd party libraries. Each library is shipped with a license file. These I automatically copy to the deployment folder, where the compiled files are (my own executable and all dependencies).

My question is related to the dependencies of those dependencies. In my mind I should not include those (since we can get into a situation "X of a Y of a Z ...", not to mention cyclic dependencies "X of a Y of a Z of a X") but just to be sure: do I have to copy/mention dependencies of 3rd party software that **I do not directly use in my own**?

Comment: This is most likely answered already on Open Source SE. See for example https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9273/how-to-handle-license-for-third-party-packages

Comment: Not exactly. But thanks for the link (didn't know this part of stackexchange even existed). It mentions MIT license specifically and the author of the answer uses expressions such as `I believe`. Since the product I'm working on is closed-source (but to my knowledge all the direct 3rd party dependencies are MIT, BSD 3 clause etc. licenses, so no GPL or similar) I need to know exactly what the legal aspect is.

Comment: "I believe" that Open Source SE is still the best place to find or get an answer to this. For legal advice, by the way, everyone here as well will tell you you'll need to hire a lawyer. Even if they don't say it outright, any kind of mention here always implies "I believe", unless they quote some documents that you can verify for yourself. Over on Open Source SE, to make the answer grounded we usually quote relevant parts of the licenses themselves, or of other relevant documents and published opinions about open source issues.